# YouTube like horizontal scroll div

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-events

I am trying to achieve a horizontal scroll div section with arrow marks for (right and left) scrolling.

What I achieved is scrolling but it is infinite scrolling, scrolling should stop after the end has reached.

What I tried so far:

```
<div class="scrollleft" style="float: left; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">LEFT</div>
    <div class="container scrollbar"
    style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width:100%;">
       <div > some content </div>
        <div > some content </div>
        <div > some content </div>
        <div > some content </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrollright" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">RIGHT</div>
```

Script :

```
$('.scrollright').click(function() {

  event.preventDefault();
  
  $('.scrollbar').animate({
    marginLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "fast");
 });

$('.scrollleft').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.scrollbar').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "fast");
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold index of currently selected div, and check if it's within range (from 0 to number of divs)

```
var numberOfDivs = $(".container>div").length;
var index = 0;

$('.scrollright').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (index <= 0)
    return;
  index += 1;

  $('.scrollbar').animate({
    marginLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "fast");
 });

$('.scrollleft').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (index >= numberOfDivs)
    return;
  index -= 1;

  $('.scrollbar').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "fast");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `event.preventDefault();`. You will have to define the end for each of the two directions. For the `scrollright` click, the end is 0, and for the `scrollleft` click, the end is the width of the `window` minus the width of the `scrollbar` (but you put it to 100%, so I subtracted 200 for now):

```js
var BoxCount = 4;
var BoxWidth = 100;
var ScrollDistance = BoxWidth; //It can be any other value if you like.
var ScrollButtonWidth = 50;

$('.scrollright').click(function() {
  var current = parseInt($('.scrollbar').css("margin-left"));
  var end = $(window).width() - BoxWidth - ScrollButtonWidth;
  var move = ScrollDistance;
  if(current < end){
    if((end - current) < BoxWidth)
      move = end - current;
    $('.scrollbar').animate({ marginLeft: "+=" + move }, "fast");
  }
  else{
    $('.scrollbar').animate({ marginLeft: end }, "fast");
  }
 });

$('.scrollleft').click(function() {
  var current = parseInt($('.scrollbar').css("margin-left"));
  var end = - (BoxWidth * (BoxCount - 1));
  var move = ScrollDistance;
  if(current > end){
    if((current - end) < BoxWidth)
      move = current - end;
    $('.scrollbar').animate({ marginLeft: "-=" + move }, "fast");
  }
  else{
    $('.scrollbar').animate({ marginLeft: end }, "fast");
  }
 });
```

```css
.scrollleft, .scrollright{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scrollleft:hover, .scrollright:hover{
  background-color: #999;
}

.container{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* 100% - (2 * ScrollButtonWidth) */
  background-color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scrollbar{
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentbox{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollleft" style="float: left;">&lt;</div
><div class="container">
  <div class="scrollbar">
     <div class="contentbox">content-1</div
     ><div class="contentbox">content-2</div
     ><div class="contentbox">content-3</div
     ><div class="contentbox">content-4</div>
  </div>
</div
><div class="scrollright" style="float: right;">&gt;</div>
```

Comment: the right scroll is not working  , but the left scroll is moving but showing blank space , initially left shouldnt respond , it shouldd work only after some content is moved to right.  If u see my code there i 've put overflow-x: hidden for container div , if it is visible we will get a horizontal scroll bar, i jus want to do that horizontal scrolling but not with that scroll bar , but with arrow buttons for right an left. like how youtube has a horizontal scrolling for their videos .           Same issue with ur solution too @Lichwa

Comment: I was wondering about the direction, but you said in your question **what i achieved is scrolling but it is infinite scrolling, scrolling should stop after the end has reached**, so I did not touch that. All what I did is defining the ends. Anyway, your code is too far from what you actually want. To get what you want, you need to define the size of your content, the scrollbar, and the scrollleft/scrollright among several other calculations you have to do. Check my updated answer. It should be very close to what you want.